# Keep RDP Session Alive After Disconnect

Tags: sql, remote-desktop, rdp

Maybe there is a better way.  Here is what I want to do.
I connect and download quotes all day and night using Web Server / Browser Based Application and SQL Database.  How can I move this session to my web server so I do not have to use local resources to manage this process?  When I connect to my Web Server using RDP, it will, of course, log me off all applications (including web browser) when I exit.
Thank for help and advice.
Craig

Comment: What OS are you using? In any case, if you are using the same user Windows should not log you off.

Comment: wow.. i did not know i could shut down the session locally and it would still run on the server... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RDP you should not be logged off. The session should remain even if you close RDP. But if you want to perform automatic repetitive tasks on a server, you should look into cron jobs, services or daemons, instead of relying on a user session with a running application.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I had no idea I could disconnect from RDP without shutting down the session.. :) !!